# How to create React Native Firebase v7 push notification Channel

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have install the react native firebase notificaiton ,notifications are working fine but when i try to send custom sound it wont work.
I find out that on Android version > 7 we have to create firebase channel in order to play custom sound but i dont know how to and where to create notification channel.

I have created two files inside the src folder of the root folder of my project where i handle notificatons.
1.LocalNotificationService.js
2.FcmService.js

Code for LocalNotificationService.js

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
// import { notifications } from "react-native-firebase";

class LocalNotificationService {
  configure = (onOpenNotification) => {
    PushNotification.configure({
      onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log('[LocalNotificationService] onRegister', token);
      },
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log('[LocalNotificationService] onNotification', notification);
        if (!notification?.data) {
          return;
        }
        notification.userInteraction = true;
        onOpenNotification(
          Platform.OS === 'ios' ? notification.data.item : notification.data,
        );

        //Only call callback if not from foreground
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
        }
      },

      // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      },

      // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
      // default: true
      popInitialNotification: true,

      /**
       * (optional) default: true
       * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
       * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
       * - if you are not using remote notification or do not have Firebase installed, use this:
       *     requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
       */
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
  };
  unregister = () => {
    PushNotification: this.unregister();
  };

  showNotification = (id, title, message, data = {}, options = {}) => {


    PushNotification.localNotification({
      ...this.buildAndroidNotification(id, title, message, data, options),
      title: title || '',
      message: message || '',
      playSound: options.playSound || true,
      soundName: options.soundName || 'default',
      // sound:'test',
      userInteracsstion: false, /// boolean if the condition was opened by the user from the notification
    });
  };

  buildAndroidNotification = (id, title, message, data = {}, options = {}) => {
   
    return {
      id: id,
      //    sound:"test",
      autoCancel: true,
      largeIcon: options.largeIcon || 'icon',
      smallIcon: options.smallIcon || 'test_icon',
      bigText: message || '',
      subText: title || '',
      color: 'green',
      vibrate: options.vibrate || true,
      vibration: options.vibration || 1000,
      priority: options.priority || ' high',
      importance: options.importance || 'high', // (options) set notification importance , default high
      // data : data,
    };
  };

  cancelAllLocalNotification = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      PushNotificationIOS.removedAllDeliveredNotification();
    } else {
      PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotification();
    }
  };

  removedDeliveredNotificationById = (notificationId) => {
    console.log(
      '[LocalNotificationService] removeDeliveredNotificationById: ',
      notificationId,
    );
    PushNotification.cancelLocalNotfication({id: `${notificationId}`});
  };
}

export const localNotificationService = new LocalNotificationService();
```

Code for FcmService.js

```
import  messaging  from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
// import type {Notification,NotificationOpen} from 'react-native-firebase'
import { Platform } from 'react-native'

class FCMService {
    register = (onRegister,onNotification,onOpenNotification) => {
        
        this.checkPermission(onRegister)
        this.createNotificationListeners(onRegister,onNotification,onOpenNotification)
    
    }

    registerAppWithFCM = async() => {
        if(Platform.OS === "ios"){
            await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
            await messaging().setAutoInitEnabled(true)
        }
        
    }

    checkPermission = (onRegister) => {
        messaging().hasPermission()
        .then(enabled => {
            if(enabled) {
                //User has permission
                this.getToken(onRegister)
            }
            else{
                //User Dont have permission
                this.requestPermission(onRegister)
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Permission Rejected",error)
            })
    } 

    getToken = (onRegister) => {
        messaging().getToken()
        .then(fcmToken => {
            if(fcmToken) {
                onRegister(fcmToken)
            }
            else{
                console.log("User Dont ave a Device Token")
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("get token rejected", error)
        })
    }
        
        requestPermission = (onRegister) => {
            messaging().requestPermission()
            .then(() => {
                this.getToken(onRegister)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Request Permission Rejected",error)
            })
        }

        deleteToken = () => {
            console.log("Delete Token")
            messaging().deleteToken()
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Delete token error",error)
            })
        }

        createNotificationListeners = (onRegister, onNotification,onOpenNotification) => {

            messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
                console.log("onNotificationOpenedApp notification caused to open app")
                if(remoteMessage){
                    const notification = remoteMessage.notification
                    onOpenNotification(notification)
                }
            });

            //When the application is opened from a quite state.
            messaging().getInitialNotification().then(remoteMessage => {
                    console.log("getInitialNotification notification caused to open app")
                    if(remoteMessage){
                        const notification = remoteMessage.notification
                        onOpenNotification(notification)
                    }
            })

            //Foreground state messages 
            this.messageListner = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
                console.log("A new FCM Message Arrived",remoteMessage)
                if(remoteMessage){
                    let notification = null
                    if(Platform.OS === "ios") {
                        notification = remoteMessage.data.notification
                    
                }else{
                    notification =  remoteMessage.notification
                }
                onNotification(notification)
            }
            })
        }
        unRegister = () => {
            
    }

    export const fcmService = new FCMService()
```

App.js

```
import React  , {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import {View,StyleSheet,Text,Button,TextInput} from 'react-native'
import {fcmService} from './src/FCMService'
import {localNotificationService} from './src/LocalNotificationService'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';


export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    fcmService.registerAppWithFCM()
    fcmService.register(onRegister,onNotification,onOpenNotification)
    localNotificationService.configure(onOpenNotification)

    function onRegister(token) {
      console.log("[App] onRegister: ",token)
      setTokenwa(token)
    }

    function onNotification(notify) {
      console.log("[App] onNotification: ",notify)
      const options = {
        soundName : 'test',
        playSound : true
      }
      localNotificationService.showNotification(
        0,
        notify.title,
        notify.body,
        notify,
        options
      )
    }

    function onOpenNotification(notify) {
      console.log("[App] onOpenNotification : " , notify)
      alert("Open Notification" + notify.body)
    }

    return () => {
      console.log("[App] unRegister")
      fcmService.unRegister()
      localNotificationService.unregister()
    }

  }, [])

  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);

  const [code, setCode] = useState('');

  const [tokenwa, setTokenwa] = useState('');


  // Handle the button press
  async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    setConfirm(confirmation);
  }

  async function confirmCode() {
    try {
      console.log("code send")
      await confirm.confirm(code);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Invalid code.');
    }
  }

  if (!confirm) {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Phone Number Sign In"
        onPress={() => signInWithPhoneNumber('+91 7769948296')}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Text>{tokenwa}</Text>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Sample React Native Firebase </Text>
      <Button title="Press Me" onPress={() => localNotificationService.cancelAllLocalNotification}></Button>
      <TextInput value={code} placeholder="test" onChangeText={text => setCode(text)} />
      <Button title="Confirm Code" onPress={() => confirmCode()} />
    </View>

    </>
  )

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    flex : 1,
    alignItems : 'center',
    justifyContent : 'center'
  }
})
```

Comment: react-native-firebase v6 removed support for custom channel, If you want to send custom sound, you have to configure Notification Payload object from server side.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref       

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options